# Should I carry my passport for a domestic flight in Germany

Tags: germany, lufthansa, domestic-travel, identity-cards

I am a foreign national having a German residence permit. I have to catch a domestic flight operated by Lufthansa to Munich from Hamburg and back. Unfortunately, my passport is with the UK consulate for a tourist visa processing.

I would like to know if a Aufenthaltserlaubnis (German residence card) is sufficient to take the domestic flight or should I have my passport with me even if the travel is within Germany.

Comment: I know from experience that you can fly LH from MUC within Schengen without ever having to show ID, if you have already checked in online. Not sure about HAM. I would try it, check in online before and bring your Aufenthaltserlaubnis along in case anyone asks, plus maybe photocopies of your passport that you will surely have and any other form of ID (license) that you might find.

Comment: It's hard to believe you'd need a passport for a flight entirely within Germany.

Comment: @JoeBlow in some countries foreigners need a passport to go to the corner store.

Comment: Hey phoog!  I'm sure that's correct: this is about Germany right?

Comment: Your _Aufenthaltserlaubnis_ is only valid together with your passport. Auslaenderbehoerde in Berlin recently told me that carrying that card without the passport is not enough. It's like a visa on a separate card. A regular visa wouldn't be valid if you ripped it out of your passport. Just having the card with you is not enough for the police (as discussed in below answers).

Comment: Have you considered asking the UK consulate to give you the passport back? If you explain the situation, they might simply expedite your visa, or give it back and tell you to bring it when the visa is ready. I've seen the embassy of the Republic of Ireland in Berlin do that. They were very friendly and accommodating.

Comment: @JoeBlow: "It's hard to believe you'd need a passport for a flight entirely within Germany." - no, it's not, actually. It may not be the case, but given that any German citizen is obliged to have at least either a passport or an ID card, and likewise, any foreigner within Germany is obliged to have a passport (or an ID card for some EU countries), it would be absolutely not a big deal to require anyone flying within Germany to bring their passport/ID card. It's not like anyone would be required to suddenly have a form of document they otherwise wouldn't.

Comment: hey OR ... are you talking now about passports, or ID cards?  maybe 30%? (wild guess) of adult germans have a passport; it seems almost certainly impossible you'd be required to have a **passport** to travel between Munich and Frankfort.  (Passports are something you get to travel to foreign lands.) Anyway this ia ll moot as the question has been answered extensively below.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper That's completely accurate... but still hard to believe when you haven't been raised there or in another country that kind of requirement!

Comment: @JoeBlow: I was referring to both passports and ID cards. The OP only mentioned passports, but as they say they are not a German citizen, whether traveling with a German ID card would be possible is irrelevant to them.

Comment: Hi OR.  No worries but *"I would like to know if a Aufenthaltserlaubnis (German residence card) is sufficient to take the domestic flight or should I have my passport with me even if the travel is within Germany"* it's difficult to see it could be any clearer.  Does OP need a passport to board the flight

Comment: Just take the train ;-) j/k

Comment: Just to clarify: from your other SE questions, you seem to be Indian; is this so? Your location is listed as Spain, which first made me think you were Spanish, in which case you could use your Spanish national ID and wouldn't need a passport, but if you are Indian, that obviously does not apply.

Comment: @Janus as a Spanish national, they would not get a visa (_Aufenthaltserlaubnis_) in Germany. They could remain indefinitely with their Spanish ID or passport. So they can't be Spanish. They have to be from a non-EU country, otherwise they can't have an _Aufenthaltserlaubnis_.

Comment: @simbabque Good point!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've flown many times on Schengen flights and no one (except Ryanair) has ever demanded to see my passport when I presented my residence permit. Likewise I've sometimes managed to enter on board without showing *any* identification, but this has been the exception. You should also be able to use the [automatic boarding gates](https://www.lufthansa.com/us/en/Boarding) at both airports:

> When you are travelling with etix® - Lufthansa’s electronic ticket -
>   and have received a boarding pass with a barcode, you have the option
>   of boarding your aircraft quickly and conveniently with this boarding
>   pass. Just use our Quick Boarding machines at selected gates at
>   Frankfurt, Munich, Dusseldorf, Cologne, Hanover, Hamburg and Bremen!

Even Ryanair has an [extremely lenient policy](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/terms-and-conditions/termsandconditionsar_368204930) for intra-German flights:

> Any photo ID which matches the passenger name in the booking.

So the answer is: **yes**, they will let you on board.

Answer (score 10):

There is an [FAQ on the federal ministery of the Interior about residence permits](http://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/FAQs/DE/Themen/Migration/Auslaenderrecht/03.html). Unfortunately, one can not simply switch to english, and I didn't find it on the english site.

It states:

> **Muss ich immer meinen Pass oder Passersatz mit mir führen?**
>
> Nein, aber Sie müssen auf Verlangen den Ausländer- und Polizeibehörden Ihren Pass bzw. Passersatz und Ihren Aufenthaltstitel vorlegen.
>
> [...]
>
> - Wenn Sie keinen Pass besitzen, diesen auch nicht zumutbar erhalten können oder Ihren Pass vorübergehend einer deutschen Behörde überlassen haben, müssen Sie umgehend einen Ausweisersatz beantragen.

which translates to

> **Do I always have to have my passport or replacement with me?**
>
> No, but upon request of police or aliens authorites, you have to present your passport or replacement **and your residence permit**
>
> [...]
>
> - If you do not have an ID, you can not get it with reasonable effort, or have passed it temporary  to a German authority, you must apply for a replacement passport.

---

So, it boils down to: You don't need to have your passport with you, but if police asks, you have to present it...

ID card and passport are the only official documents to confirm your identity, the residence permit is only a supplement.

There is no general passport control for flights within the Schengen area and you can often board an aircraft without showing your passport anywhere. Airline staff *may* be fine with anything *looking* official, like residence permit or drivers license. But it is still possible that police asks you for your passport. Maybe, you get away with your story, maybe, not.

(Within this context, it is interesting how a consulate can take your passport, leaving you without any official ID. As German, you can easily get a replacement as requested by the last paragraph of the quote, but for others... hmmm)

Sorry, I don't have a solution for your particular problem, this is just the law.

Comment: This is about the general ID requirement in Germany and that's a slightly different question. And you don't need to present it to the police *on the spot* (that's why they say you don't have to carry it with you) so there is no reason for this law to be used to prevent you from boarding a plane.

Comment: As to why consulate do it that way, the fact is that in many other countries, carrying an ID is not required and/or a local residence permit is the only thing foreigners need. There is no reason for consulates to bend over backwards to accommodate this German peculiarity.

Comment: Will you criticize all the answers that aren't going in your direction? Looks like you are missing the spirit of this forum here...

Comment: There's a similar law in Czech Republic but the police commonly ignores it and is satisfied with seeing the residency permit. The permit is easier to verify anyway.

Comment: @Relaxed: This is all true. But: If police stops you somewhere on the airport, they can prevent you to board the plane. The chance for being asked to provide ID is high at an airport. And even if you don't have to  not show ID _on the spot_, how much time do you have to show it? Can you say "in two weeks, when I'm back from Hamburg"?

Comment: @Maurice It's not a criticism, just a minor nuance, this answer, unlike yours, is precise and useful. In fact, when I wrote my comment, I did not realize you would see it as a vindication because it says something completely different than what you are trying to read into it. You really should educated yourself about all this before commenting any further.

Comment: @sweber don't bother arguing with Relaxed, this is just a loss of time... looks like he has a bad day today...

Comment: @sweber I believe it's 24 hours. Still, no legal basis to deny boarding. What you risk is a fine and I see no reason why you could not show your passport to another police station. Also, the police cannot perform ID checks without a specific reason, I am not sure whether there is actually a higher chance or any legal basis for them to perform random checks at airports.

Comment: Hi @sweber !  Your answer relates to *do I need to carry a passport in Germany?*.  It does not seem to relate to the question asked here on this page.  ("What will the airline Lufthansa ask me for on a flight to Munich from Hamburg?")

Comment: According to the rest of the FAQ you quoted, the OP needs to get a _Passersatz_ (document that acts like a passport, [link in German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passersatz)). I haven't figured out yet what kin of document that would be exactly. It does sound like a lot of trouble to get that because you can't just go to _Buergeramt_ and ask for a temporary one which they would do immediately for a German national.

Comment: @sweber Obviously applies to Germans as well, since without any ID, how could the police know that you are German? (Although for Germans, any official ID with a picture is fine to identify you).

Answer (score 4):

On intra-Schengen flights, there is no *systematic, police-performed* checking of identity documents which would require a passport or ID card or similar. And moreso for truly domestic flights (crossing a Schengen border you are *de jure* required to have ID with you even if it isn’t checked. Within Germany you are typically not required to have an ID on you all the time).

However, either the airline or the airport may want to confirm that you are indeed the traveller that should be travelling on the ticket in question. For that, they may want to see some form of identification.

Unfortunately, I couldn’t find anything definite on Lufthansa’s website as to which documents are accepted for domestic flights (they only go into detail for international flights). It is entirely *possible* that given your circumstances your residence permit (which is government-issued) or a driving license (with a picture) would suffice.

The definite answer can only be given by the airline, though.

Answer (score 1):

My girlfriend is a foreigner with german residence card, and while I advise her to take her passport on all our trips, she almost never needs to show it unless we cross a non-Schengen border.

On flights within the EU, passports or ID cards are rarely checked at all. Even less so on national flights. At HAM, which I've used regularily, ID is rarely requested for national flights, but I've seen it happen (not to individuals, rather a "please show your passport and boarding pass when boarding" announcement).

So practically, you should be fine. That doesn't mean the airline can not cause you trouble, either legally or illegally. Many people have been denied entry into Schengen countries, sued and won. So to be certain, you should ask the airline, in writing, and get a written response that you carry with you.

Comment: I typically ignore *please show your passport and boarding pass* announcements and show my boarding pass only. Only on one occasion to date (leaving Amman airport bound for Munich) has this been a problem.